# Cannot ping github.com

Tags: github

From time to time I have an issue to access gihub.com from ONLY one computer in my home network either through the web browser or just simply using ping/tracert command

My computer is Windows 7, firewall is disabled. So far I noticed this issue only while connecting to github.com

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping github.com

Pinging github.com [192.30.253.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

C:\Users\test\Desktop>tracert github.com

Tracing route to github.com [192.30.253.113]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Attie Clearly not an issue in this case as tracert is timing out on hop 1.

Comment: in Chrome I am getting message "github.com took too long to respond"